# java graphics variables giving wrong value

Tags: java, variables, graphics

Hello I wonder if anyone can help me , I have declared 2 values x1, y1 both as 120 and trying to use these in the following method:

```
private void drawDot(int x, int y, Graphics2D twoD) {

    twoD.fillOval(x-50, y-50, 100, 100);

}
```

However when I use drawDot(120,120,twoD) it paints the filled oval in the wrong place compared to when I manually use

```
twoD.fillOval(70,70,100,100);
```

Shouldn't these 2 statements do the exact same thing? Is there something I am missing? I have added an image to show the issue, the oval on the left is the oval drawn by my drawDot method and the oval on the right is the oval in the correct place as it should be. If anyone has any advice it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

[click this link to see how both ovals are drawn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3poN.png)

the entire class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DieFace extends JPanel {

int x1,y1 = 120;
int x2,y2 = 300;
int x3,y3 = 480;

private BufferedImage bufferedImage;

public DieFace() {

    this.init();
    this.frameInit();       
    updateVal(1);

}

private void init() {

    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,600));

}


private void frameInit() {

    JFrame window = new JFrame("Dice Simulation");
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setContentPane(this);
    window.pack();
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    Graphics2D twoD = (Graphics2D) g;
    twoD.drawImage(bufferedImage,0,0,null);

}

private void drawDot(int x, int y, Graphics2D twoD) {

    twoD.fillOval(x-50, y-50, 100, 100);

}

public void updateVal(int dieRoll) {

    bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(600,600,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D twoD = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
    twoD.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    twoD.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
    twoD.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    if(dieRoll==1) {

        drawDot(x1,y1,twoD);
        twoD.fillOval(70, 70, 100, 100);

    }

    repaint();

}

}
```

Comment: From the posted information, that's impossible to answer. Yes, the statements should be equivalent, but there may be many reasons for your observations. First and foremost: Maybe there is a `graphics.translate` call between the drawing operations?

Comment: there is no graphics.translate call, I will post the whole class now so that you can see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Shouldn't these 2 statements do the exact same thing? Is there something I am missing?

Because you made a mistake in your variable initializations on `x1`, `y1`:

```
int x1,y1 = 120;    //This means x1 = 0, y1 = 120
```

What you actually wanted is:

```
int x1 = 120, y1 = 120;
```

---

Since `x1` is not 120, when you invoke

```
drawDot(x1,y1,twoD);
```

`drawDot(0, 120, twoD);` is being invoked

Hence both elipses will appear on the same y-axis, but different on the x-axis.